# Auto refresh Excel Power Query when a particular cell changes (I am using VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, powerquery

I am importing an Access database into an Excel workbook. I want to filter the table I am importing automatically based on the value of a cell in the Excel worksheet. I have been able to do that through Power Query code.

Next step is updating the table I am importing every time the cell value changes. I have been able to update the query every time **any cell** in the whole sheet (the one where the key cell is) changes using this code in VBA:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll

End Sub
```

I would like to edit that VBA code so that the Power query **only updates when the particular cell that I am using to filter the table changes**, not when any cell in the sheet changes.

Appreciate any tips!

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using this code which refreshes only the query I want instead of refeshing all queries in the workbook:

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address = Me.Range("[Cell Reference]").Address _
Then

    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query - [Name of the query]").Refresh

End If

End Sub
```

In my case, [Cell Reference] was B5 and [Name of the query] was BS.
The code must be added in the Sheet module where the cell or range (B5 in my case) is located.

Answer (score 0):

not tested.  Something like:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

if not intersect(cell_to_check, Target) is nothing then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
end if

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, Ron. I understand I would only need to change the "cell_to_check" part of your code, right?. I am not sure how to reference cells in VBA. I have checked a couple of ways but none of them seemed to work.

The cell I want to reference is named as 'TeamNBA' and is on the A2 cell of the NBA sheet ("NBA!A2").

Sorry for my VBA naiveté.

Comment: Many ways: Try `Range("TeamNBA")` or `[TeamNBA]` or `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("NBA").Cells(2,1)` or ...